# How make video and audio duration the same with ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, concatenation

I am merging a few user-generated videos together with [ffmpeg-concat](https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/ffmpeg-concat) and sometimes run into an audio sync issue. I figured that it fails when audio and video duration mismatch. E.g.:

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 IMG_7679.mov
16.666016
ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 IMG_7679.mov
16.670998
```

Question is — how do make audio and video duration equal prior to concat, without loosing the content?

Or maybe classic ffmpeg's concat solves this issue somehow and I should use it?

Comment: Seems like the real question is, *"How to make video and audio sync in ffmpeg-concat?"*

Comment: Not really. Ffmpeg-concat just needs the files to have an equal duration of audio and video. Guess it's a requirement, otherwise, everything goes out of sync, and the more the videos to cancat, the more noticeable is the sync issue.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `trim` and or `atrim` filter to cut a part of the audio or video.

```
[v]trim=0:3.23,setpts=START-PTS[vout]
[a]atrim=0:3.23,asetpts=START-PTS[aout]
```

setpts and asetpts fixes the timestamps

Comment: Thanks, but this will cause a loss of content (either video or audio), won't it?

Comment: yes, though here we talk about lik 10 ms so it's not noticable. second thing would be adding blank data, but still, would you add it to the end or the front? Then stretching could also do something, but could remove some frames and i don't know what is the reason for which you have different sizes.

Comment: so unless you know exactly why you have different lengths, it doesn't make a difference to do something else

Comment: I work with user-generated videos shot on smartphones and those always have different duration of audio and video tracks. Weirdly, sometimes the audio is longer, and sometimes the video is. But you are right, it's usually a matter of ms. Will try what you suggested. I also found this but I am not sure what it does
`[input]aresample=async=1:first_pts=0,apad,atrim=0:10[filtered]`