# ffmpeg processed video has a few seconds missing at the end after uploaded and processed by Vimeo

Tags: ffmpeg, vimeo

We process the videos using ffmpeg 4.4 as mp4 using x264 with aac audio. After we upload them to Vimeo some of them have a shorter length than the original.

E.g. one video is missing 6 seconds from the end. Another is missing 3 seconds from the end. Some are processed correctly.

What format should I upload the videos to Vimeo so they do not loose those seconds or what settings do you recommend so videos are not cut?

I researched Vimeo's recommendations https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360056550451-Video-and-audio-compression-guidelines and also ffmpeg recommendations.

Also I tried to encode x265 and I have the same issue only different seconds missing: same video (original is 12 minutes and 19 seconds)

- x264 - becomes at Vimeo 12:13
- x265 - very blurry at 5K bitrate had to increase and length was 12:15

Thank you.

**Edit 1:** After further testing I found [How make video and audio duration the same with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63530641/how-make-video-and-audio-duration-the-same-with-ffmpeg) and https://superuser.com/questions/650291/how-to-get-video-duration-in-seconds

ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=dura
tion -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -sexagesimal /video.avi

ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=dura
tion -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -sexagesimal video.avi

0:12:19.134694 audio
0:12:19.045930 video

This still is not does not get the correct difference shown when uploading to Vimeo.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help anybody with the same issue:

By using ffmpeg 4.4 when converting to mp4 H264 aac it will check the video stream and audio stream and if the video stream is longer it will cut it to the audio stream length. Older versions did not do this.

In order to solve this I followed the below steps:

1. I checked the audio and video stream length of the avi and mp4 file with the below commands (from the links above):

ffmpeg -i video.avi |& awk '/Duration:/ {print $2}'

ffmpeg -i video.mp4 |& awk '/Duration:/ {print $2}'

2. If these did not match I would calculate the number of frames * missing seconds (if the mp4 duration < the avi duration)
3. I would duplicate the last video frame for the length needed using:

-filter_complex tpad=stop={number_of_missing_frames}:stop_mode=clone

Make sure you replace {number_of_missing_frames} with what was the result in step 3.

This will produce an mp4 with the correct, equal length video and audio streams and if you upload them to Youtube or Vimeo they will be processed correctly.